# Updated varchar column data to jsonb data

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update a column from a varchar type column into a JSON but the column is already filled in with varchars how can I cast them to turn into a JSON with additional information.

**Table structure with data:**

```
-----+--------+
| id  | value  |
+-----+--------+
| 1   | value1 |
| 2   | value2 |
| 3   | value3 |
| 4   | value4 |
| 5   | value5 |
| 6   | value6 |
+-----+--------*
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----+----------------------------------+
| id  |             value                |
+-----+----------------------------------+
| 1   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value1"} |
| 2   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value2"} |
| 3   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value3"} |
| 4   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value4"} |
| 5   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value5"} |
| 6   | {"t1": "val", "value": "value5"} |
+-----+----------------------------------*
```

Kindly help me to resolve this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae5054b418427ea05c51e7c98a98a5c1)

When altering a column type you can add an expression to convert the data from the old type into the new one. You have to add the `USING` clause in order to do so:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ALTER COLUMN "value" TYPE json USING json_build_object('t1', 'val', 'value', "value");
```

In this case use the `json_build_object()` function to create the expected JSON object incl. the old value